# How to access the value of each checkbox in a table with Flask?

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a table which is populated by

```
 <button type="submit" name="update" value = company.index style = margin-left:45%>Update</button>
                ....
                {% for product in products%}
                    <tr {{product .index}}>
                        <th scope="row">{{ product .productname }}</th>
                        <td> {{ product .description }} </td>
                        <td><form method = "POST"> <input  type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{product .index}}"  value = {{product .index}}{% if product .like == 1 %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}></form>{{product .like}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
```

Which populates a table depending on how many products are in the list `products`. I am then in `app.py` trying to see if any boxes are checked (which all have different names), the problem is that, if I have multiple rows which are chceked, only the first row is the one that returns a value.

`app.py`

```
  @app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
  def index():
      ....
      for key in request.form:
         print(key)
  return render_template('index.html', products = products)
```

So if my list `products` contains 3 products, they will each be on one row in the table, and all have one box next to them. But when I check in all the boxes and press the update button, only the name of the first button will be printed. How do I access the value of all the buttons which are present in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You again haha

the problem is that you have a form-element for each product, so if you want to check every item you need to wrapp all these items with the form-element.

Another option is to use javascript as I mentioned in your other question. then you could remove all form elements and would use a javascript function instead.

Example:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% for product in products%}
        <tr {{product .index}}>
            <th scope="row">{{ product .productname }}</th>
            <td> {{ product .description }} </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{product .index}}"
                    value={{product .index}}{% if product .like == 1 %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}>
                {{product .like}}
        </td>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" name="update" value="company.index" style="margin-left:45%">Update</button>
</form>
```